# How to pass SQL connection as part of post body

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a central service for generating Jasper report which uses database connectivity.
I also have another service which call the jasper service with report parameter and Sql connection using Post call and receives Byte[] of PDF.

currently when ever I am making call to Jasper service it throws below error:

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException' exception.
```

followed by:

```
Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection["metaData"]...
```

my way of creating JDBC template, Datasource and connection is as below:

```
@Bean(name = "myServiceDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mydatabase.dev")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new BasicDataSource();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }
```

creating connection:

```
Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

I am wrapping connection, report parameter and other info in input Vo and making rest call as below:

```
restTemplate.postForObject(generateUrl, inputVO, byte[].class);
```

could you please help, what I am doing wrong here which is stopping me to make post call and throws exception

Comment: You're trying to send an SQL connection object via an HTTP POST? Please, review how HTTP works, and understand that makes no sense.

Comment: Why do u need to pass a connection object to client side? I think you are trying to pass values after query execution. You should pass values retrieved from database.Seems, you are not clear about of the flow of the application.

Comment: I have more than one DB where data differers but they have same procedure call. The jasper service can be called by more than one service and based on the service DB info it fetched the database. hope I am able to explain @JonathonReinhart

Comment: It is a huge security issue to allow a client to specify anything about the SQL connection. You should derive the connection parameters from some other well-checked entity, like a "service name".

Comment: My problem is the Jasper service is using open source and it should follow open source licencing agreement, hence I can not provide my datbase info in jasper service.@JonathonReinhart

Comment: That makes no sense at all.